# React Router V4 - How can I give a unique route to a modal or overlay, without unrendering the component from the previous route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7S3n.jpg
Using reddit as an example, here is a gif of what I am trying to achieve. From the initial route(the feed), they click on a post and are directed to a new route of an overlay(the post) which is rendered while the feed behind it is still rendered(if you hide the post overlay in dev tools the feed is still there). I looked into nested routes to accomplish this but it seems any nested routes can only be appended to current routes, where as I would want a completely new route name(there is a profile overlay which is able to be opened from many different pages, so instead of appending "/profile" to all those separate routes, it's desired for it just be "/profile". I'm not sure if this is possible with just react-router, or would require redux or something of the sort.